# Sending a class as a parameter to a thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parameters

So I am trying to find a way to dynamically pass a class type to a thread, so it can recall the class that it was issued by, and thereby dynamically return data to that class again.

Here is what I am trying, where ServerClass is the class of this main function:

```
public static void Main()
{
    UDPClass clsUDP = new UDPClass();
    Thread clsUDPThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate() { clsUDP.UDPListen(64000, ServerClass); }));
    clsUDPThread.Start();
}
```

This is the receiving end, in the UDPClass:

```
public void UDPListen(int UDPPort, Type OldClass)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a lot with code like this.

```
class X : BaseClass
{ 
   ...
}

class Y : X
{ 
    int yField;
}

...

int Main(BaseClass instance)
{ 
    if (instance is Y) (instance as Y).yField = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the line as follow:

```
Thread clsUDPThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate() { clsUDP.UDPListen(64000, typeof(ServerClass)); }));
```

Although, only accepting type will not solve your problem - you need to actually accept the instance (object) of the type (assuming you want to invoke instance methods/properties). The better way would be to accept an interface that your target type must implement.

EDIT:

Ok - here's how you would use an interface.

```
public interface IUDPListener
{
   void Notify(string status);
}
```

In UDP class,

```
public void UDPListen(int UDPPort, IUDPListener listner)
{
  ...
  listener.Notify("bla bla");
  ...
}

public class ServerClass : IUDPListener
{
   ...

   public void Notify(string status)
   {
     // Callback from thread
     ...
   }

   // Method that starts thread
   public void StartThread() 
   {
     UDPClass clsUDP = new UDPClass();
     Thread clsUDPThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate() { clsUDP.UDPListen(64000, this); }));
     clsUDPThread.Start();
   }   
}
```

You can also use a delegate for such notifications if its a simple one method callback. With interface, you can define multiple callbacks and also methods/properties to query the listener if needed. Here's the sample code using delegate

In UDP class,

```
public void UDPListen(int UDPPort, Action<string> callback)
{
  ...
  callback("bla bla");
  ...
}
```

In server class

```
public class ServerClass
{
   ...
    private void UdpCallback(string message)
    {
       ...
    }

    // code to start thread
    UDPClass clsUDP = new UDPClass();
    var clsUDPThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate() {clsUDP.UDPListen(64000, UdpCallback); }));
    clsUDPThread.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ParameterizedThreadStart to call a method with parameters in a new thread.

```
public static void Main()
{
    UDPClass.UDPListenParameters threadParameters = new UDPClass.UDPListenParameters();
    threadParameters.UDPPort = 64000;
    threadParameters.OldClass = this.GetType();

    UDPClass clsUDP = new UDPClass();
    Thread clsUDPThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(clsUDP.UDPListen));

    clsUDPThread.Start(threadParameters);
}

public class UDPClass
{
    public void UDPListen(object parameter)
    {
        UDPListenParameters parameters = (UDPListenParameters)parameter;
        // parameters.UDPPort
        // parameters.OldClass
    }

    public class UDPListenParameters
    {
        public int UDPPort;
        public Type OldClass;
    }
}
```

But as VinayC pointed out, you would need to pass a reference to the server class instead of the type to be able to use it's members.